How to build an efficient full text search through multiple joined tables
Ok I have 7 Tables that I want to join for my search.

recipe_base < recipe_name
recipe_base < recipe_description
-> (multiple languages for recipe_name & recipe_description)

Then I also want to enable a search through tags:

recipe_base < recipe_tags < tag_names -> (multiple languages again for tag_names)

As well as on cookwares:

recipe_base < recipe_cookwares < cookware -> a recipe has mostly multiple cookwares which are in multiple languages

Now I'm struggling building my Text Search. Because I can't figure out how to build my joins in the way that they are effective but also don't contain duplicates.
To have a bit more context here are the defined tables:
CREATE TABLE recipe_base
(
    recipe_id  UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    creator_id UUID,
    image_url  VARCHAR          NOT NULL,
    proteins   DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    fats       DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    calories   DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_name
(
    recipe_id UUID NOT NULL,
    language  VARCHAR,
    name      VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, language)
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_description
(
    recipe_id   UUID NOT NULL,
    language    VARCHAR,
    description VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id, language)
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_tags
(
    tag_id    DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    recipe_id UUID             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, recipe_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tag_name
(
    tag_id   DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
    language VARCHAR          NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, language)
);

CREATE TABLE recipe_cookwares
(
    recipe_cookware_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    recipe_id          UUID     NOT NULL,
    cookware_id        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    total_time         SMALLINT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE cookware
(
    cookware_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    language    VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cookware_id, language)
);

My main problem is (I think at least) that a user can create recipes. In order to keep the cross product as small as possible, I only want the recipe bases that have the current user_id as the creator. On top I want to aggregate my cookwares and tags. But I only seem to get it through sub joins which would ignore the filtering of the recipe_base until a later point. So how can I structure my query more efficiently?
SELECT
    fr.recipe_id,
    rname.name AS recipe_name
FROM
    (
    SELECT recipe_id
    FROM recipe_base
    WHERE creator_id IS NULL OR creator_id = '4b816bc6-d9c2-41f7-b0e3-263dd54b24c4'
    ) AS fr
        LEFT JOIN recipe_name AS rname ON fr.recipe_id = rname.recipe_id AND rname.language = 'de' OR rname.language IS NULL
        LEFT JOIN recipe_description AS rdesc ON fr.recipe_id = rdesc.recipe_id AND rdesc.language = 'de' OR rname.language IS NULL
        LEFT JOIN recipe_tag AS rtag ON fr.recipe_id = rtag.recipe_id
        LEFT JOIN tag_name AS tname ON rtag.tag_id = tname.tag_id AND tname.language = 'de'
        LEFT JOIN recipe_cookware AS rcook ON fr.recipe_id = rcook.recipe_id
        LEFT JOIN cookware AS cook ON rcook.cookware_id = cook.cookware_id AND cook.language = 'de'
WHERE (setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rname.name, '')), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rdesc.description, '')), 'A') || setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(tname.name, '')), 'B') || setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(cook.name, '')), 'C')) @@ to_tsquery('german', 'Gn:*');

And this is the sub join approach I came up with, but obviously the filtering sucks ass:
SELECT
    fr.recipe_id,
    rname.name AS recipe_name
FROM
    (
    SELECT recipe_id
    FROM recipe_base
    WHERE creator_id IS NULL OR creator_id = '4b816bc6-d9c2-41f7-b0e3-263dd54b24c4'
    ) AS fr
    LEFT JOIN recipe_name AS rname ON fr.recipe_id = rname.recipe_id AND (rname.language = 'de' OR rname.language IS NULL)
    LEFT JOIN recipe_description AS rdesc ON fr.recipe_id = rdesc.recipe_id AND (rdesc.language = 'de' OR rdesc.language IS NULL)
    
    -- Aggregate Tag Names Inline
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtag.recipe_id, string_agg(tname.name, ' ') AS aggregated_tags
        FROM recipe_tag AS rtag
        LEFT JOIN tag_name AS tname ON rtag.tag_id = tname.tag_id AND tname.language = 'de'
        GROUP BY rtag.recipe_id
    ) AS rt ON fr.recipe_id = rt.recipe_id
    
    -- Aggregate Cookware Names Inline
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rcook.recipe_id, string_agg(cook.name, ' ') AS aggregated_cookware
        FROM recipe_cookware AS rcook
        LEFT JOIN cookware AS cook ON rcook.cookware_id = cook.cookware_id AND cook.language = 'de'
        GROUP BY rcook.recipe_id
    ) AS rc ON fr.recipe_id = rc.recipe_id
    
WHERE
    (setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rname.name, '')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rdesc.description, '')), 'A') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rt.aggregated_tags, '')), 'B') ||
     setweight(to_tsvector('german', coalesce(rc.aggregated_cookware, '')), 'C')
    ) @@ to_tsquery('german', 'Gn:*');

